# Retrieving values from Python dictionary with different variable types

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

In a dictionary such as:

```
dict = [{'author':'Joyce', 'novel': 'Dubliners'},
{'author':'Greene','novel':'The End of the Affair'},
{'author':'JD Salinger','novel':'Catcher in the Rye'}]
```

How can I retrieve all the novels with a comprehension using 'author' as the *key*.

Comment: You want a list of novels for a specific author?

Comment: Don't use `dict` as an identifier - it is a python type.

Comment: What do you mean using `'author'` as key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use list comprehension

```
[x["novel"] for x in dict if x["author"] == author_name]
```

getting all the novels:

```
[x["novel"] for x in dict]
```

Comment: How can I get all the novels, not just the one written by a specific author?

Comment: Thank you. Please change it to 'novel' in the singular so that the code is seamless.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for all the books for a specific author:

```
>>> author = 'Joyce'
>>> [d['novel'] for d in data if d['author'] == author]
['Dubliners']
```

All novels:

```
>>> [d['novel'] for d in data]
['Dubliners', 'The End of the Affair', 'Catcher in the Rye']
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess a result given by this was expected, but I'm not sure if there is an easy way to do this using comprehensions.

```
books = [{'author':'Joyce', 'novel': 'Dubliners'},
    {'author':'Greene','novel':'The End of the Affair'},
    {'author':'JD Salinger','novel':'Catcher in the Rye'}]

nbooks = {}
for book in books:
    author = book['author']
    novel = book['novel']
    nbooks.setdefault(author, []).append(novel)

print(nbooks['Joyce'])
```